# ¿Como generar múltiples inputs?

Tags: javascript, json

Me gustaría saber como puedo generar múltiples inputs dinámicamente con diferentes `class=""` o `id=""`, mediante un botón "Add more" y que con otro boto genere un JSON multidimensional, y enviarlo por ajax, el único código que tengo hasta ahora, es este:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields = 4;
var wrapper = $(".input_fields");
var add_button = $(".add_more");
var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(x < max_fields){
x++;
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remover</a></div>');
}
});
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent('div').remove();
x--;
})
});
```

Quiero que genere un JSON de esta forma:

```
{
"texts": {
"text1": "Input1",
"text2": "Input2",
"text3": "Input3",
"text4": "Input4"
},{
// ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo el siguiente HTML:

```
<a class="add_more">Add more</a>
<div class="input_fields"></div>
<hr>
<a class="view_result">Ver JSON</a>
<pre></pre>
```

Puedes probar esta solución:

```
$(function(){
    var max_fields = 4;

    $('.add_more').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $wrapper = $('.input_fields');

        //validamos la cantidad de inputs
        if($wrapper.find('input').length == 4) return;

        //creamos el input
        var $input = $("<div><input type='text'> <a>Remover</a></div>"); 

        //le agregamos la funcionalidad de eliminarlo
        $input.find('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $input.remove();
        });

        //lo añadimos al contenedor
        $('.input_fields').append($input);
    });

    //extraer los valores
    $('.view_result').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var result = {};

        //recorremos los inputs y los añadimos al objeto 'result'
        $('.input_fields input').each(function(i, e){
            result['text'+i] = $(e).val();
        });

        //lo muesta
        $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

Puedes probarlo en: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXGqYr)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el código funciona tal y como esperaba, de verdad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno a lo que entiendo quieres hacer un botón que agregue mas campos inputs, y cuando se vayan a enviar obtenga esos inputs y los meta en JSON, para enviar...

1.- Crea un botón que agregue un input al final del contenedor que estés teniendo para eso...

2.- con jquery, obtener el contenedor, e iterar los hijos e obteniendo cada ítem y metiendolos en un arreglo (array).

3- ya que preparaste tu array, convertir ese array en json y mandarlos a donde quieres que se procese...